# Read loop wont terminate

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I can't seem to get this read loop to terminate.

```
#include <unistd.h>
char buffer[256];
int read_chars;
while((read_chars = read(STDIN_FILENO,buffer,sizeof(buffer))) > 0) { 
  //DO STUFF
}
```

However, when I hit enter in the terminal, it just hangs for the next read and never exits.

Any thoughts on this implementation is not correct ?

Comment: Probably because `stdin` is blocking.  Maybe you need a sentinel value, such as `'\n'` to `break` out of the loop.

Comment: correct, however read man page says: "In the absence of any errors, or if read() does not check for errors, a read() with a count of 0 returns zero and has no other
       effects."  so a 0 return should end the loop.

Comment: The thing is `\n` is a valid char sended to the buffer, you need to force EOF: Press CTRL+D if you are on Linux or CTRL+Z then intro on Windows

Answer (score 1):

Here `read` will stop reading at the end of standard input, which a newline isn’t. Try doing `Ctrl-D` twice in your terminal while the program is reading and it should terminate. `Ctrl-D` once on an empty line or twice after some characters marks the end of standard input.

Comment: This does work. Any toughts as to why this works without needing CTRL+D then?

while(read(STDIN_FILENO,buff,sizeof(buff))> 0)

Comment: @Equinox that is the exact same function call of your question. It does not work without closing `stdin` with CTRL+D or any other method.

Comment: hmmm... seems to work here. Terminates the loop without needing CTRL+D